# Create a guessing game till I want to stop

Tags: dev-c++

I'm new to programming, I'm trying to turn modify this program so that i can enter guesses until I want to stop. any help would be great!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    char name[10][20]= {"DUMBO","MICKEY MOUSE","GOOFY","DONALD DUCK"};
    char charName[20];
    int count;
    char found;

    printf("Enter the name of a Disney cartoon character ");
    gets(charName);
    strupr (charName);
    found = 'n';

      for (count=0;count<4;count++)
    { if(!strcmp(charName, name[count]))
        {found = 'y';}
    }

    if(found == 'y')
        puts("Match");
        else
        puts("No Match");

        system("pause");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: You have to put gets and the condition if found=='y' inside your loop perhaps

Answer (score 0):

A good way to keep it going is to use a while loop. I'm not that familiar with C++, but the general idea would be:

```
declare list of names

nameMatch = 0

while nameMatch == 0:
    Ask the user to enter a name
    if input == one of the names
        puts("Match")
        nameMatch = 1
    else
        puts("No Match")
```

That way it'll keep asking until the user picks the right name, or any other condition you want to set.